# How to find flashlight feature is available or not in device < = sdk 4

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight

I used to find the flashlight is available or not using this code

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

but this code is support for sdk version >= 7 lower version is not supporting. so anybody help to find whether the flashlight is available in lower version

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android SDK has Camera class.. you can try getFlashMode method .. If method return null then flash is not support...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFlashMode()

I have not tried it,

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with the newer Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean hasFlash() {
        if (camera == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        if (parameters.getFlashMode() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        List<String> supportedFlashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (supportedFlashModes == null || supportedFlashModes.isEmpty() || supportedFlashModes.size() == 1 && supportedFlashModes.get(0).equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```