# LED flash light activation

Tags: android, camera, android-context, led

I am trying to use the flash LED that is built into my android device. I found an existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android) that was very helpful but I am seeing a strange compile error now. The problem is the part of my code where I check availability of flash.

```
boolean FlashAvails=Context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

There is a compile error that reads "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method getPackageManager() from type Context".

Comment: The variable is not static so I do not understand why I am receiving this message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method getPackageManager() is not static, according to the Javadoc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

You'll need to get a reference to the context and then you can call the method.

To get a reference to the context you can all:

```
Context appContext =  Context.getApplicationContext();
```

Then you can get access to the package manager as follows:

```
appContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Make sure to include the import:

```
import android.content.Context;
```

Assuming you're using Eclipse, you can press: ctrl-shift-o and it will reorganize your imports and pull in anything that's missing.

If you're still having trouble, another way is to get the Camera Parameters, as described in this posting: [How to find flashlight feature is available or not in device < = sdk 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145370/how-to-find-flashlight-feature-is-available-or-not-in-device-sdk-4)

Comment: How do I get a reference to the context?

Comment: So does Context.getApplicationContext() replace "Context" in my original post? That does not compile either. How do I make a non-static reference to the method while accomplishing what I want

Comment: What error are you getting? I've updated my answer to explain what I'm talking about.